# How to align p tag with radio button

Tags: html, css

[image]

The above image is how I want my output to be. But instead i'm getting this. 
[image]

This is my code. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

```
<p class = "one" style = "text-indent: 198pt;"><font size = "2px">*How likely is that you would recommend</p><p class = "one" style = "text-indent: 272pt;">freeCodeCamp to a friend?</font>
<form class = "f2">
        <input type = "radio" id = "1" >
        <label for = "1">Definitely</label> <br>
        <input type = "radio" id = "2" >
        <label for = "2">Maybe</label> <br>
        <input type = "radio" id = "3">
        <label for = "3">Not Sure</label> <br>
</form>
</p>
```

Comment: a form inside a p? font tag in HTML is being deprecated in HTML5

Comment: I'm new to HTML so i'm just doing what seems right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Rejig your HTML to include a wrapper and the use flexbox.

Also:

- Don't split continuous text across 2 paragraphs
- The `<font>` element is obsolete and should no longer be used.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width:90%;
  margin:1em auto;
}

div * {
  flex:1;
}

p {
  text-align:right;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class = "one"> *How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
<form class = "f2">
        <input type = "radio" id = "1" >
        <label for = "1">Definitely</label> <br>
        <input type = "radio" id = "2" >
        <label for = "2">Maybe</label> <br>
        <input type = "radio" id = "3">
        <label for = "3">Not Sure</label> </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grid?

```
.grid{
  display:grid;
  width:100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}


<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <p class = "one" style = "text-indent: 198pt;">*How likely is that you would recommend</p>
    <p class = "one" style = "text-indent: 272pt;">freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
  </div>
  <form class = "f2">
    <input type = "radio" id = "1" >
    <label for = "1">Definitely</label> <br>
    <input type = "radio" id = "2" >
    <label for = "2">Maybe</label> <br>
    <input type = "radio" id = "3">
    <label for = "3">Not Sure</label> <br>
  </form>
</div>
```